# unable to get desired output using string format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code is as below. I am trying to have the str_list to be replaced as `'10','11'` in the `'{}'`
but what I get is `'10,11'`. May someone help me to get my desired output?

```
str_list = '10,11'
self.query= "select ball_name from ball_data where ball_type in ('{}')".format(str_list)
```

The desired query

```
"select ball_name from ball_data where ball_type in ('10','11')"
```

What I currently get is below

```
"select ball_name from ball_data where ball_type in ('10,11')"
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split it on `,`, add the single quotes, then join it back:

```py
self.query = "... in ({})".format(",".join("'" + x + "'" for x in str_list.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_list = '10','11'
query= "select ball_name from ball_data where ball_type in {}".format(str_list)`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65429649/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27919515)

Comment: @minglyu in fact it does, the output query is as desired, you can get such definition of `str_list` easily by `str_list = tuple(str_list.split(","))` from OPs one, should be added here tho, this answer seem to be more efficient than accepted to me